# Abstract and Concrete Categories: The Joy of Cats, Are there any solutions for the review questions or solution guide?

Tags: category-theory

Does anyone have solutions for the exercises in "Abstract and Concrete Categories: The Joy of Cats"? I'm working my way through them, and want to check my answers.